# Can't enable breadcrumbs on a Category specific page

Tags: admin, layout, layout-update

I never used this before, but now I would like to specify the layout update in the Backoffice.

In the template for this category I have `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>` specified, but on the global level I have breadcrumbs in another matter, but on this particular page I would like to leave them as it is.

I'm trying to add this to the category layout update:

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" before="content" as="breadcrumbs" template="page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml" />
</reference>
```

But it doesn't affect anything...

I'm missing something here, because if I put `<remove name="header" />` it works perfectly.

Thank you,

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by `but on the global level I have breadcrumbs in another matter, but on this particular page I would like to leave them as it is.`. Are you removing breadcrumbs globally via a layout file, but wish them to stay for just this page?

Comment: I'm adding them in other format, breadcrumbs go to the custom category header witch doesn't exist's on this particular category.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by layout handler and  magento is creating an individual handler for each Catgoet render by below logic.

```
'CATEGORY_' . $category->getId().
```

I.E `CATEGORY_$YOurCategoryId`

That means it dynamic handler.
 and using  this dynamic handler and remove tag we can remove breadcrumbs from specific Category.

```
<CATEGORY_MYCATID>
<reference name="root">
<remove name="breadcrumbs" /> 
</reference>

</CATEGORY_MYCATID>
```

**Example:** Suppose category id is 8 from which you want to remove breadcrumbs

```
<CATEGORY_8>
<reference name="root">
<remove name="breadcrumbs" /> 
</reference>
</CATEGORY_8>
```